# Why the BeginScrollView is working fine in the inspector editor script but it's not working in the editor window script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the inspector editor script that is working fine with the scroll view :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ConversationTrigger))]
public class ConversationTriggerEditor : Editor
{
    private Vector2 scrollPos;
    private ConversationTrigger conversationtrigger;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        conversationtrigger = (ConversationTrigger)target;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Height(250));
        DrawDefaultInspector();
        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Add new conversation"))
        {
            conversationtrigger.conversations.Add(new Conversation());
        }

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        if (conversationtrigger.conversations.Count == 0)
        {
            GUI.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.enabled = true;
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("Remove conversation"))
        {
            if (conversationtrigger.conversations.Count > 0)
                conversationtrigger.conversations.RemoveAt(conversationtrigger.conversations.Count - 1);
        }

        GUILayout.Space(100);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Save Conversations"))
        {
            conversationtrigger.SaveConversations();
        }

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Load Conversations"))
        {
            Undo.RecordObject(conversationtrigger, "Loaded conversations from JSON");
            conversationtrigger.LoadConversations();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the editor window script that use and show the same as in the inspector but in the editor window the scroll view is not working. I can scroll up/down the scroll bar just not moving at all :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

public class ConversationsEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    Vector2 scrollPos;

    [MenuItem("Conversations/Conversations System")]
    static void Init()
    {
        const int width = 800;
        const int height = 800;

        var x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        var y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        GetWindow<ConversationsEditorWindow>().position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        var ff = FindObjectOfType<ConversationTrigger>();
        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
        EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Width(800), GUILayout.Height(800));
        var editor = Editor.CreateEditor(ff);
        var tar = editor.targets;
        editor.OnInspectorGUI();
        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
        Repaint();
    }
}
```

And another bothering thing is when I'm changing the number of conversations in the editor window in the int field or the number of dialogues I need first to click with the mouse on some empty space area of the window above the changed field to make the changes take affect. Then it's collapsing the root and I need to expand it again :

In the screenshot there is one conversation :

[image: One Conversation]

When I'm typing and changing instead 1 for example to 20 nothing happen :
There is still only one conversation :

[image: Still one conversation]

I need to close the Conversations root first :

[image: Closed the conversations]

Now when I click on it and open it again then I will see the 20 conversations :

[image: 20 Conversations]

1. How can I make that when changing the size of conversations and/or dialogues and/or sentences it will add/remove the items in real time ?
2. In the last screenshot you can see the scrollview bar that is not moving. I can't move it up/down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question seems to be actually: Why does the List in the Editorwindow not get updated?

As I guess I told you once before you should use `SerializedProperty` in custom editor scripts, not directly change component values without markingt the object as *dirty*.

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(ConversationTrigger))]
public class ConversationTriggerEditor : Editor
{
    private Vector2 scrollPos;
    private SerializedProperty conversations;
    private ConversationTrigger conversationTrigger;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        conversations = serializedObject.FindProperty("conversations");
        conversationTrigger = (ConversationTrigger)target;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Height(250));
        DrawDefaultInspector();
        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();

        // Load the current values from the real component into the serialized copy
        serializedObject.Update();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Add new conversation"))
        {
            conversations.arraySize++;
        }

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        if (conversations.arraySize != 0)
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button("Remove conversation"))
            {
                if (conversations.arraySize > 0) conversations.arraySize--;
            }
        }

        GUILayout.Space(100);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Save Conversations"))
        {
            conversationTrigger.SaveConversations();
        }

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Load Conversations"))
        {
            // Depending on what this does you should consider to also 
            // change it to using the SerializedProperties!
            Undo.RecordObject(conversationtrigger, "Loaded conversations from JSON");
            conversationTrigger.LoadConversations();
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

As you can see the Scrolling works perfectly for me:

[image]

---

And also once more I can only strongly recommend to use `ReorderableList` for what you are doing. It is slightly more complex to set it up but so extremly powerful:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(ConversationTrigger))]
public class ConversationTriggerEditor : Editor
{
    private Vector2 scrollPos;
    private SerializedProperty conversations;
    private ConversationTrigger conversationTrigger;
    private ReorderableList conversationList;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        conversations = serializedObject.FindProperty("conversations");
        conversationTrigger = (ConversationTrigger)target;


        conversationList = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, conversations)
        {
            displayAdd = true,
            displayRemove = true,
            draggable = true,

            drawHeaderCallback = rect =>
            {

                EditorGUI.LabelField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, 100, rect.height), "Conversations", EditorStyles.boldLabel);

                var newSize = EditorGUI.IntField(new Rect(rect.x + 100, rect.y, rect.width - 100, rect.height), conversations.arraySize);

                conversations.arraySize = Mathf.Max(0, newSize);
            },

            drawElementCallback = (rect, index, isActive, isSelected) =>
            {
                var element = conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

                var name = element.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                // do this for all properties

                var position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(rect, new GUIContent(name.stringValue));

                EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, name);
            },

            elementHeight = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight
        };
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // Load the current values from the real component into the serialized copy
        serializedObject.Update();

        scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Height(250));

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        conversationList.DoLayoutList();

        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();

        GUILayout.Space(100);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Save Conversations"))
        {
            conversationTrigger.SaveConversations();
        }

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Load Conversations"))
        {
            Undo.RecordObject(conversationtrigger, "Loaded conversations from JSON");
            conversationTrigger.LoadConversations();
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

[image]

---

And use this to fix the EditorWindow

```
public class ConversationsEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    private ConversationTriggerEditor editor;

    [MenuItem("Conversations/Conversations System")]
    static void Init()
    {
        const int width = 800;
        const int height = 800;

        var x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        var y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        var window = GetWindow<ConversationsEditorWindow>();
        var ff = FindObjectOfType<ConversationTrigger>();
        window.position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
        window.editor = (ConversationTriggerEditor)Editor.CreateEditor(ff);
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        editor.OnInspectorGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working fine for the Inspector but still when I'm changing the size for example of the Conversations it's not changing it at real time when I'm typing in the int field of the Conversations size. I need to close the Conversations and open it to see the changes.

Comment: Working great for the Inspector. But why I can't expand the items the Conversations and see the Dialogues and Sentences childs of each Conversation like before ? How do I do it also for the editor window script ? And is it right behaviour if I set in the Inspector the size of Conversations for 1000 that everything become very very slow ? It's working smooth on size of 100 items 200 even 300 but 1000 make it very slow.

Comment: well the Inspector is very limitted .. it gets slow for too many drawen items yes. Added the last section for the editorWindow. You don't need to add an additional scrollrect ... instead use the one the editor already has

Comment: There are two problems not problems but somethings I wonder how to change. How can I remove the Conversations size int field out of the scrolling view ? When setting for example 100 items then the Conversations int field is moving up and you need to scroll up each time to make change/s. Second thing is when clicking the + plus to add new items it's pushing the plus and minus + - down inside so I wonder how to move them also out the scroll view at the bottom. And last is how can I make that when adding new item with the plus button it will add new empty item ? Now it's duplicating the last item

Comment: 1. Like I used in the ReordeableList example you could make an `EditorGUILayout.IntField` for changing `conversations.arraySize` outside of the scrollview. 2. Not sure if it is possible. This would require the ReorderableList itself using a scrollview which isn't the case. You could ofcourse fake it and disable adding and removing for the ReorderableList and instead use the two buttons from my first example again for adding and removing always the last item 3. You can override `onAddCallback` and set all values of the new added element to default.

Comment: Any progress btw with your account merging? ;)

Comment: I just got a message I see now in my gmail that the request for the merging accounts has expired. I will make a request now again.

Comment: I tried to add a callback like this : public override void onAddCallback()
    {

    } But I'm getting error on the onAddCallback : no suitable method found to override